# document.fullScreen Opera

Tags: javascript, fullscreen, opera

I'm trying to get the state of full-screen mode. Script works fine in all browsers except Opera. How to solve this?

```
$(document).bind('webkitfullscreenchange mozfullscreenchange fullscreenchange',function(){
        if(document.fullScreen||document.mozFullScreen||document.webkitIsFullScreen){
            console.log(' Enter Fullscreen ');
        }else{
            console.log(' Exit Fullscreen ');
        }
});
```

Comment: @Zenith did not help (

Comment: Sorry, I meant `document.fullscreenElement`. In fact, this one alone should work for Chrome, Firefox, Opera and Safari

Comment: @Zenith Strangely enough, but does not work in Opera. Maybe there are some other ways?

Comment: Which version of Opera are you using? According to the documentation it's supported from v12.10 - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/DOM/Using_full_screen_mode

Comment: Also, this may help - https://github.com/neovov/Fullscreen-API-Polyfill/issues/3

Comment: @Zenith ``Opera/9.80 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.8.4) Presto/2.12.388 Version/12.15 (Core 2.12.388)``

Comment: Tried `document.requestFullscreen`?

Comment: @Zenith So, it helps! Thanks! Waiting for your reply!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, you're using the non-standard way of achieving this (`mozFullScreen` etc.), [**according to the documentation**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/DOM/Using_full_screen_mode).

In Firefox, Safari, Chrome and Opera 12.10,`document.fullscreenElement` is the standard and will achieve what you want.

However, in newer versions of Opera, there seems to have been a few bugs (see [**here**](https://github.com/neovov/Fullscreen-API-Polyfill/issues/3) and **[here](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/pull/2161)**) in regard to `fullscreenElement`.

The workaround to these bugs in newer versions of Opera is to use `document.requestFullscreen` instead.